# Mocking vue-router's push() method in Unit testing - Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, vue-router, vuejs3

I'm new to Vue and StackOverflow, but I'll try to explain my problem.

I get a TypeError when I try to run the unit test for my application.

"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqUkZ.png

The program runs exactly as it should otherwise, it's only the test that fails.

The test tries to run $router.push in the application, but can't, because it doesn't know what that is, how can I successfully mock the push method while testing?

My example.spec.js test code looks like this:

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import LoginView from '@/views/LoginView.vue'

describe('LoginView.vue', () => {
  it('loginSuccess-test', async () => {

    const wrapper = shallowMount(LoginView, {
      mocks: {
        $router: {
          push: () => {}
        }
      }
    })

    await wrapper.setData({username:'user', password:'pass'})
    await wrapper.find('button').trigger('click')
    const statusId = wrapper.find('#loginstatusLabel');

    expect(wrapper.find('#loginstatusLabel').element.textContent).toBe('true')

  })
})
```

My LoginView.vue methods code looks like this:

```
  methods: {
    checkCredentials() {
      if (this.username === 'user' && this.password === 'pass') {
        this.loginSuccess = 'true';
        this.$router.push({ name: 'home' });
      }
      else {
        this.toast.error("Username or password is incorrect    Try again");
        this.message = 'Login failed!';
        this.isActive = false;

      }
    }
</script>
```

I'm trying to make the push method redirect the user to "home" when he successfully logs in and mock the redirection in testing.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In vue3 you need to wrap the `mocks` property inside `global` property

Vue2

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(LoginView, {
  mocks: {
    $router: {
      push: () => {}
    }
  }
})
```

Vue3

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(LoginView, {
  global: {
    mocks: {
      $router: {
        push: () => {}
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Source: https://test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/vue-router.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
mocks: {
        $router: {
          push: jest.fn(),
        }
      }
```

Comment: I've already tried that, but the same TypeError gets thrown.